# Connecting to mysql from perl using apache webserver?

Tags: mysql, perl, apache, windows-xp

I am trying to test connectivity for the first time.like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
# DBD::ODBC
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $dsn = 'DBI:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server}';
#my $host = 'localhost';
my $host = 'mysql';
my $database = 'test';
my $user = 'root';
my $auth = 'mukesh';
# Connect via DBD::ODBC by specifying the DSN dynamically.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("$dsn;Server=$host;Database=$database",$user,$auth) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

but i am getting this error agian and again.
`Got error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000) when connecting to`

Is there anything i need to configure in my pc before doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using a Microsoft SQL server connection to a MySQL database - that isn't going to work.

You possibly want something like;

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host;port=3306";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $auth) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
```

But you also seem to be confused about the host - are you sure the host name for the mysql database is 'mysql'? If it's running on the same machine, localhost would be correct.

I also hope those aren't your real root credentials - perhaps posting those in a public forum isn't a great idea, but also connecting as root is almost certainly not what you want to do, consider using a specific user with only the required permissions.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now but i am getting this another error now `Database connection not made: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at C:/Apache2/cgi-bin/testdbi.pl` .. I have a pasword for root

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MySQL.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI();

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db_name;host=localhost",
        "db_user", "password",
        {'RaiseError' => 1});

main();
exit(0);

sub main {
    testMySQL();
}
sub testMySQL() {
    if ($dbh) {
        print "Connection to the server successful!";
    }
}
```